# How to quickly view a function's documentation when using jupyter-notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

It seems that using '?' command is the only way.But this is too much trouble, need to run the function？ in another cell.
I've tried shift+tab, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Shift + TAB displays popup with signature, docstring and type.

One can also keep open Inspector where documentation will be displayed while typing.

[image]